Need to OCR a Dutch book with text formatting preserved
The problem
I need an English translation of a large document written in Dutch. My strategy of getting that is to (a) scan the document, (b) OCR the page images to get the Dutch text, then (c) use translation software to render the text into English. I don't know Dutch, but I have a Dutch colleague who can help evaluate intermediate and final results. I don't have a big budget for this, so I need to use tools that are either free or low cost.
Currently I'm stuck at step (b), getting good OCR.
Results from Adobe Acrobat
I have Adobe Acrobat, so I've used that to scan the document. I've had trouble before getting good OCR of Dutch from Acrobat, even with the OCR language set to Dutch, and the same was the case here. However, there were also some very good things about the Acrobat OCR that I haven't found in other OCR software:
The Good

Acrobat keeps the original formatting of the text, including font size, bold, and italics. I get this because after it OCR's the document and makes a pdf of it, I can save the pdf as a docx, and that docx has all the text formatting of the original document. That is very helpful.
Acrobat correctly recognizes most letters with diacritics (i.e., accent marks, such as "á").
It distinguishes end-of-line hyphens from hyphens in the middle of a line by rendering the former as a soft hyphen (ASCII 173) followed by either a space or a newline. I was therefore able to remove these by global replaces. This is not a perfect solution because sometimes a hyphen at the end of a line is a correct part of the word and should not be replaced. But it's far better then simply interpreting the end-of-line hyphen as the same as an ordinary hyphen.

Despite these positive features, the Acrobat OCR has so many errors that it's essentially useless. The types of errors it made are:
The Bad

Sometimes rendering a lower case "L" in the middle of a word as "!".
Sometimes rendering a capital "I" as a lower case "L".
Sometimes rendering an "h" as "b".
Sometimes inserting a space in the middle of a word or between a word and a subsequent period.
Sometimes treating a letter with an accent mark incorrectly, either ignoring the mark (e.g., "ë" --> "e") or rendering an umlaut as a subsequent colon (i.e., "ï" --> "i:").
Sometimes other errors.

None of these errors was very frequent. The ignoring of an umlaut will probably not usually cause an incorrect translation, and vowels followed by colons can probably be safely globally replaced with the letter with the umlaut. But the incorrect "!"s, "l"s, "b"s and spaces seem to occur altogether often enough to give me concerns about the accuracy of the translation that I'll get.
Results from Amazon Textract
With all those errors from Acrobat, I decided to try Amazon's OCR, called Textract. It made far fewer errors, but had the following problems:

Although it handled most diacritics (accent marks) correctly, it had trouble with accented "e"s. Often, it would simply ignore the mark (e.g.,  "ë" --> "e"), as Acrobat did, and sometimes it even changed it to the wrong one (e.g.,  "ë" --> "è").
End-of-line hyphens were converted to "- ", i.e., an ordinary hyphen, not a soft hyphen (ASCII 173), followed by a space. It is not safe to do a global removal of those because a hyphen followed by a space is not uncommon.
Despite Textract having the helpful ability to parse pages into headings, tables, and ordinary text, it has no recognition of font characteristics. So in cases where a passage is emphasized by use of bold or italics, that emphasis is lost.

Other candidates
I asked ChatGPT about this, and it told me of a half-dozen software packages that can do OCR preserving text formatting, along with a list of pros and cons of each: ABBYY FineReader, Readiris, Google Drive OCR (via Google Docs), Microsoft OneNote, Nuance OmniPage, and Tesseract (with hOCR Output).
Question
What software can you recommend for this project?
